# Find the average of string in python

Tags: python

I have an string in python (with float and integer numbers)

```
string = '44,44,44,33'
```

I want to calculate the mean of that.

Note: I have one large dataframe, and in one column of the dataframe, I have such a string. I want to calculate the mean for all rows. I hope I there is an efficient way for that.

Thanks

Comment: That's a list containing a string, not a string.

Comment: Get the first element of the list, then use `split()` to split that at the comma characters. Call `int()` on each element of that. Then calculate the average of those.

Comment: First break your string into the the number components then convert the string numbers to integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spilt string, covert to integers, and calculate mean:

```
import statistics
result = statistics.mean(map(int, string.split(",")))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = string.split(',')
average = sum(int(k) for k in l)/len(l)
```